# Coibir o uso de repositórios externos de código em pergunta sem código

Tags: novo-recurso

Hoje eu vi uma pergunta na qual o AP expôs sua dúvida de forma bem sucinta. Porém, ao invés de adicionar o código na própria pergunta, foram inclusos links para o pastebin.

Nada contra o uso de sites como o Pastebin, ou os fiddles da vida. São uma ajuda e tanto. Porém **se o link quebrar, a pergunta fica sem sentido** - o que leva a uma situação na qual ela pode ser fechada por não estar clara o suficiente após ter tido várias boas respostas.

A minha ideia não é impedir completamente o uso desses sites pois seria algo extremo. Pensei em ao invés disso utilizar a seguinte validação: permitir o uso de sites como Pastebin, jsFiddle etc. **somente no caso em que houver ao menos um bloco de código na pergunta**. Acho que isso seria bom para respostas também.

*"Mas Renan, isso tornaria o uso do site externo redundante"* - sim, e isso seria vantajoso para ambos os lados. Quem abre a pergunta acaba sendo obrigado a fazer sua parte pela preservação dos [patinhos de borracha (adote um hoje mesmo)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210323/o-que-%C3%A9-um-pato-de-borracha-e-para-que-serve), e quem vai responder não precisa acessar outra fonte para ver um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Os sites externos seriam apenas para executar código que o próprio SO não seja capaz de rodar em um snippet, ou para maiores esclarecimentos de código muito grande.

<sup><sup>Sério, pensem nos patinhos. Toda vez que alguém coloca código apenas em sites externos Deus mata um patinho de borracha.</sup></sup>

Comment: Salvem os patos de borracha!11

Comment: Claro que todo mundo pode pegar lá e editar a pergunta com o código. O que é pior é o fato do cara largar o código lá de qq jeito e a gente que se vire para ler tudo interpretar o que faz parte do problema ou não, onde está o problema e descobrir o que deveria estar fazendo porque certamente aquele código não pode ser compilado.

Comment: Quem dera bloqueassem o mal uso de tantas coisas como esta, agora como fazer isso é complicado :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fazer a sugestão que eu dei é fácil. O SO já tem inteligência suficiente para colorir as palavras chave do código que você posta, por exemplo. Descobrir se existe pelo menos um bloco de código é fácil. Agora, depois de ler o post do Gabe, eu pensei mais sobre o assunto e acho que ele tem razão.

Comment: @Renan não quis dizer que discordo ou algo assim, apenas quis dizer que tem mais coisas que realmente são complicadas mas que creio que deveriam ser implementar e que talvez sejam fáceis de detectar, um exemplos: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274626/198279 e https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275752/198279, apenas 2 exemplos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu só tenho algumas considerações, que são grandes demais pra um comentário:

1. Trazer os trechos relevantes do código para a pergunta é excelente mas, em alguns casos, proibitivo. Nem todo problema vai ser facilmente identificado em 10-20 linhas. Conseguir afunilar dessa maneira é uma habilidade adquirida com experiência e nem todo iniciante vai ter. Sugiro ter isso em mente quando forem aplicar qualquer regra desse tipo.
2. Vale mais a pena manter uma pergunta boa no site que tenha todo o código num Pastebin/Gist do que apagá-la por um detalhe técnico. Bom conteúdo é bom conteúdo.
3. Como eu sempre defendo, uma edição vale mais que mil palavras. A **única** maneira de disseminar essa determinação, caso ela seja aprovada, é vocês editarem o máximo que puderem de perguntas assim, sempre explicando o motivo da edição e, se possível, apontando para este post. Dessa maneira, não só vocês garantem que o site vai se manter de acordo com as regras, mas os APs e outras pessoas que não participam do Meta ou não viram esse post, ficam sabendo que essa é a orientação.
4. Acho que também é importante ressaltar que há uma distinção mais que razoável entre links que apontam pra um blog qualquer de 2013, ou um site pessoal, e os que apontam para serviços como Gist ou Pastebin. Gitbhub e Pastebin são organizações tão ou mais antigas quanto o Stack Overflow e, para todos os efeitos, tão confiáveis quanto em termos de presença. Levem isso em consideração ao aplicarem as sugestões 1-3.

Comment: E para respostas?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Acredito que o mesmo se aplique, principalmente os pontos 3 e 4. Quanto a 1 e 2, vale um rigor maior em garantir que toda parte relevante da resposta esteja presente na pergunta, com certeza. Mas nada impede que partes complementares, ou exemplos, sejam colocados em outros lugares para evitar poluir a resposta.